# Can CFFILE support simultaneous writes to the file system?

Tags: coldfusion, file-upload, cffile

We have written a feature that allows our users to upload a file to a nas device using UNC path. The feature has not been stressed tested and I'm not 100% convinced CFFILE can handle the load. Does cffile use multi-threading to perform writes to the file system and what kind of load can cffile support?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a project that had numerous simultaneous writes of separate files to a local device without any problems.  I doubt CF (or, for that matter, the underlying OS) would support simultaneous writes to the same file, regardless of location, but as long as you are writing different files, simultaneous writes should be fine.

Comment: Maybe I didn't pose the question properly. They are not uploading the same file or to the same file. When they upload this file a new unique directory is created using a guid. I was just wondering of the load that CFFILE can take and can it perform simultaneous writes. We get roughly 6,000 hits per hour probably 90% of them will be using this new feature.

Comment: I've not tried it at that volume (we were getting a few thousand saves per day in about an 8 hour range) but, if the OS can handle it, I don't know of a reason CF would not.  At this point, my main concerns would be the upload speed of large files timing the page out, and possibly the total available bandwidth to the server.  The actual disk IO should be able to keep up with that.  Keep an eye out for fragmentation though, as we found that to be our main slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben's answer says, CF can write multiple files simultaneously. The first bottleneck you run into will probably be what your hardware can support. If you start running into issues, consider getting a Solid State Drive specifically for these files to be written to.